# Thread Run not working properly

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I made a simple Java program that uses a Thread object to move a square around a JPanel. The square moves to a random position, changes its color and the JPanel changes its background color. And then the thread sleeps for 1000 ms. But then I added one more line of code that adds +1 to a JLabel and the square stopped moving (while the score was working and adding +1).

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    Random random = new Random();

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    while(true) {

        width = random.nextInt(area.getSize().width) + 1;
        height = random.nextInt(area.getSize().height) + 1;

        width -= ((width - 45) > 0) ? 45 : 0;
        height -= ((height - 45) > 0) ? 45 : 0;

        this.square.setLocation(width, height);
        this.square.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/square" + (random.nextInt(4) + 1) + ".png")));
        this.area.setBackground(new Color(random.nextInt(255) + 1, random.nextInt(255) + 1, random.nextInt(255) + 1));

        //The following line works, but the setLocation method stops working.

        this.score.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(this.score.getText()) + 1));

        try {

            sleep(1000);

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(RunThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }

    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Edit: this is how I create a Thread...

```
public Click() {

    initComponents();
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);

    RunThread run = new RunThread(jLabel1, jLabel2, jPanel1);
    run.run();

}
```

Comment: Maybe the thread is getting overloaded?

Comment: Where to you start the Thread? That is do you actually start a Thread or just invoke the run() method? Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: How do you set `this.score`'s text initially? Unless you set it to a string containing an integer, `Integer.parseInt` will fail.

Comment: I invoke the run() method in the constructor of another class. So I create an instance of the thread object, I pass a JPanel and two JLabels as arguments and then invoke the run() method.

Comment: Actually, I use Integer.parseInt to add +1 to the current JLabel text and then return it to an Integer.toString, so it's converted to a string again. I know it's probably not a good way of doing that.. but it's just so I can practice threads. I learned that recently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> invoke the run() method in

Which is wrong. That is not how to use a `Thread`. If you invoke the `run()` method then it is just treated like any other method and you are not using a `Thread`. Therefore, whenever you use `Thread.Sleep(...)` you are causing the `Event Dispatch Thread(EDT)` to sleep which means the GUI can't repaint itself.

To use a `Thread`. you need to invoke the `start()` method on the `Thead`, so the code should be:

```
run.start();
```

Comment: You should also note that it's a very bad practice to modify Swing components outside the event dispatch thread. This way you will get painting errors and other kind of awful stuff. If you need to make heavy calculations or processing, you can use a separate thread , but at the time of modifying swing components you must go back to EDT using SwingUtilities.invokeLater()

Comment: Thank you for your explanation camickr. It's working just fine now!